# OAuth 2 Configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

Hi I getting an error when try to login with OAuth2 redirect_uri_mismatch. The server and the client code work fine, but i have to configure in google a new project and obtain a new google client ID for web application, and now dont's work.

This is what I have:

Mvc.WebApi.AuthServer -> It have enable OAuth2 and google auth http://localhost:50668/

Mvc.WebApi.Client-> I have to login using google against my authServer from client side http://localhost:12731/

In the Startup.cs of server:

```
googleAuthOptions = new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
        {
            ClientId = "515569638546-02hgtoe06v2k633nuk6220vdo7tqqmgg.apps.googleusercontent.com",
            ClientSecret = "FF8p4bsSIG-KT0AS8Ts-HfEb", //not real
            Provider = new GoogleAuthProvider()
        };
        googleAuthOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        app.UseGoogleAuthentication(googleAuthOptions);
```

In the .js of client:

```
$scope.authExternalProvider = function (provider) {

    var redirectUri = http://localhost:12731/authcomplete.html;

    var externalProviderUrl = "http://localhost:50668/" + "api/Account/ExternalLogin?provider=" + provider
                                                                + "&response_type=token"
                                                                + "&scope=email"
                                                                + "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri;
    window.$windowScope = $scope;

    var oauthWindow = window.open(externalProviderUrl, "Authenticate Account", "location=0,status=0,width=1000,height=750");
};
```

The above code used to work, I create this below:

Google Developer Console, the configuration of credentials
[image]

Im getting this error when I login:
400. That’s an error.
Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
The redirect URI in the request: http://localhost:50668/signin-google did not match a registered redirect URI.

Comment: The port number is different in your JS code to that in the Google Developer console (12731 and 456789 respectively)?

Comment: i changed the real ones for the sample here, but yes its confusing with the image, I edit the question with the correct ports, thank you

Comment: What's the point of having the Google provider at the server if you are passing `response_type=token` which suggests the client-side token flow that doesn't involve the server at all?

Comment: a redirect url of anything.html is almost certainly wrong. The redirect URL should be pointing at server code, not a web page. Also, the url must match character for character, and finally (although this might no longer be true) a url of localhost doesn't/didn't work. Try making it mydevserver.com and add mydevserver.com as an alias for localhost in your /etc/hosts